# Determining the context of ERC-20 Transfer event

Tags: javascript, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js, binance-smart-chain

I'm learning blockchain development building a hobby project to build a portfolio. Trying to replicate the bottom section on Poocoin/Dextools where it shows real time trades for a contract - with an indication that it's a buy/sell and the BNB/USD amount.

I've succeeded in getting half the work done where I can log real time "transfers" using following code using ethers library's event listener..

```
require("dotenv").config({});

const { ethers } = require("ethers");


var wsProvider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(process.env.WSS_URL);
// I use moralis speedy nodes as my provider

const CONTRACT_ABI = require("./myABI.json");

let contract = new ethers.Contract(process.env.TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, CONTRACT_ABI, wsProvider);


contract.on("Transfer", (from, to, amount, value, event) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
});
```

And I do get real time transaction with the following structure

```
{
  "blockNumber": 14696508,
  "blockHash": "0xd6aeef435bd4067e8b4ab75e3b7dfa2645d8d33726762e90bdeffc46c51d12da",
  "transactionIndex": 125,
  "removed": false,
  "address": "0xc748673057861a797275CD8A068AbB95A902e8de",
  "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002809d94ed7d3ca13",
  "topics": [
    "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
    "0x000000000000000000000000c736ca3d9b1e90af4230bd8f9626528b3d4e0ee0",
    "0x000000000000000000000000e962dad670434e5f69f7ef8862a597fd4b94a9fc"
  ],
  "transactionHash": "0x960aa714fdb4f2289a58b14d89facd1ea8035b03d27aba7f663bd0d179162662",
  "logIndex": 694,
  "event": "Transfer",
  "eventSignature": "Transfer(address,address,uint256)",
  "args": [
    "0xc736cA3d9b1E90Af4230BD8F9626528B3D4e0Ee0",
    "0xe962DaD670434e5f69f7Ef8862A597fD4B94A9FC",
    {
      "type": "BigNumber",
      "hex": "0x2809d94ed7d3ca13"
    }
  ]

}
```

But from this data, I cannot understand if it's a buy or a sell and what is the amount of this trade. I dug deeper to see on how to infer a "buy" or a "sell" from the above data. I made some progress and read that I could query the "transactionHash" and get more details on it and thus can classify it as a buy or a sell?

Answer (score 1):

`Transfer` event tells that tokens where transferred from address A to address B.

The context of transfer can be anything:

- User moving tokens between his own wallets
- Deposit to a centralised exchange
- Trade
  etc.

You cannot deduct based on this event if it was a buy, sell, trade or anything but a transfer.

Comment: appreciate your response. how would you suggest to listen to buy / sell events ?

Comment: I would love to answer your question, but it is too open ended. I suggest you open a new question with details what kind of buy and sell events you are interested in and what kind of preliminary research you have done what kind of ways of trading there already exist and what areas are you focusing on.

Comment: so I can stream a transaction hash-es, real time using websocket providers..  - as I posted in my question. 

When I check that on poocoin/dextools - they are able to deduce if it's a buy or a sell for that token. And they have the same transaction hash that I have. Just want to know, how can I do it..  if anyone has been facing a similar situation and you solved it - would be great!

Comment: I suggest you read XYProblem information website and it will help you to ask better questions https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I'm not sure which website to point you to for basic comprehension.. If transfer events don't give any context how are poocoin showing buys and sells?if I'm doing something wrong may be its good someone can point out where I went wrong.. Maybe I should be lookin for a different event?

Comment: I suggest you read the exchange smart contract source code and there you fill find events what the exchange is posting.